# Managing conditional statements inside Jenkinsfile & Accessing the Jenkins environment variable

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to add conditional statement inside `Jenkinsfile` for my CI/CD pipeline `kubernetes` deployment. I just added one `If-Else` condition in deployment stage and accessing the created Jenkins environment variable. But I am getting the following error,

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps
```

And My `Jenkinsfile` content contains like following,

```
agent any
environment 
    { 
        NAME = "myapp"
        VERSION = "${env.BUILD_ID}"
    }
.
.
.// Scripts for project and image builds
.
.
stage ('Test Deployment'){
steps{
    script{
        if (${VERSION} == 1){
                sh 'kubectl apply -f deployment/testdeployment.yaml'
                sh 'kubectl apply -f deployment/testservice.yaml'
            }
        else{

    sh 'kubectl set image deployment/test-kube-deployment test-kube-deployment-container=spacestudymilletech010/spacestudykubernetes:${VERSION} --record'
    sh 'kubectl rollout restart deployment/test-kube-deployment'

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am accessing build number as variable `VERSION` with notation `${VERSION}` for building image and for checking the status of deployment. In Image build stage it is properly working. When I added script block for defining the conditional statement , from that time I am getting error like this. Kindly guide me for this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use double quotes to use the environment variable inside the script block.

Try `if ("${VERSION}" == "1"){`, this should work.